# How to improve pytesseract function for capctha decoding?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, captcha, python-tesseract

I want to extract the numbers from an image in python. In order to do that, I have chosen pytesseract. When I tried extracting the text from the image, the results weren't satisfactory. I also went through the following code and implemented all the techniques listed with other answers. Yet, it doesn't seem to perform well.

sample images:
[image: a.jpg]
[image: b.jpg]
[image: c.jpg]
[image: d.jpg]
[image: e.jpg]
[image: f.jpg]
[image: g.png]

and my code is:

```
import cv2 as cv
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"E:\tesseract\tesseract.exe"

def recognize_text(image):
    #  edge preserving filter denoising 10,150
    dst = cv.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image, sp=10, sr=150)
    plt.imshow(dst)
    #  grayscale image 
    gray = cv.cvtColor(dst, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #  binarization 
    ret, binary = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    #  morphological manipulation corrosion    expansion 
    erode = cv.erode(binary, None, iterations=2)
    dilate = cv.dilate(erode, None, iterations=1)

    #  logical operation makes the background white    the font is black for easy recognition. 
    cv.bitwise_not(dilate, dilate)
    #  identify 
    test_message = Image.fromarray(dilate)
    custom_config = r'digits'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(test_message, config=custom_config)
    print(f' recognition result ：{text}')



src = cv.imread(r'roughh/testt/f.jpg')
recognize_text(src)
```

My problem with my code is that it only works with the images of '396156' & '436359' and not with any other images. Please suggest some improvement in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've solved your problem, but this kind of images must be pre-processed using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881175/remove-background-noise-from-image-to-make-text-more-clear-for-ocr). You will need to tweak the parameters. I worked with a similar dataset and aforementioned solution works well. Let me know your results.

**Editing the answer**

I'm improving my answer, to not show just link for reference.

The key for this kind of problem is image pre-processing. The main idea is to clean up the input image conserving just the characters.

- Given an input image as

[image]

- We want an output image as

[image]

The follow code contains the image pre-processing that I used based on the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881175/remove-background-noise-from-image-to-make-text-more-clear-for-ocr):

```
# loading image and checking the height and width
img = cv.imread('PNgCd.jpg')
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
print("Height: {} Width:{}".format(h,w))
cv.imshow('Image', img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

#converting into RBG and resizing the image
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # converting into RGB order
img = imutils.resize(img, width=450) #resizing the width into 500 pxls
cv.imshow('Image', img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

#gray scale
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
cv.imshow('Gray', gray)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

# image thresholdinf with Otsu method and inverse operation
thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv.imshow('Thresh Otsu', thresh)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

#distance tramsform
dist = cv.distanceTransform(thresh, cv.DIST_L2, 5)
dist = cv.normalize(dist, dist, 0, 1.0, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
dist = (dist*255).astype('uint8')
cv.imshow('dist', dist)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

#image thresholding with binary operation
dist = cv.threshold(dist, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | 
cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv.imshow('thresh binary', dist)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

#morphological operation
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_CROSS, (2,2))
opening = cv.morphologyEx(dist, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
cv.imshow('Morphological - Opening', opening)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

#dilation or erode (it's depend on your image)
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_CROSS, (2,2))
dilation = cv.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations = 1)
cv.imshow('Dilation', dilation)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

# found contours and filtering them
cnts = cv.findContours(dilation.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
nums = []
for c in cnts:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(c)

    if w >= 5 and h > 15:
        nums.append(c)
len(nums)

#Convex hull and image masking
nums = np.vstack([nums[i] for i in range(0, len(nums))])
hull = cv.convexHull(nums)
mask = np.zeros(dilation.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
cv.drawContours(mask, [hull], -1, 255, -1)
mask = cv.dilate(mask, None, iterations = 2)
cv.imshow('mask', mask)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

# bitwise to retrieval the characters from the original image
final = cv.bitwise_and(dilation, dilation, mask=mask)
cv.imshow('final', final)
cv.imwrite('final.jpg', final)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

# OCR'ing the pre-processed image
config = "--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789"
text = tsr.image_to_string(final, config=config)
print(text)
```

The code is an example to how to deal with this kind of image. We must keep in mind, Tesseract is not perfect and, it requires cleaned images to work well. This code can also fail for others images like that, we must tweak the parameters or try other techniques of image pre-processing. You must also know the `--psm` modes, in this case I've considered `--psm 7`, that treats the image as a single text line. For this kind of image, you can also try `--psm 8`, that treats the image as single word. This code is just a start point, you can improve it according your need.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30392551)

Comment: No problems, I understand. I'll improve my answer. Thanks for the advice.